# Weird regex behavior using codemirror's simple mode

Tags: javascript, regex, codemirror

I'm trying to create a mode that allows Todo.txt format which is very very simple but having a weird regex behavior when codemirror is matching results.

Basically, I'm trying to mark all lines starts with "x" following a space character and having this condition only at the beginning of a line but regex picks up a string in the middle of the line.

My regex doesn't match this condition when trying on other javascript regex tools: https://regex101.com/r/kUXTqf/1

Here is my regex line from the simple mode definition:

```
{regex: /^(x ).*$/, token: "task-completed"}
```

And the text I'm testing against:

```
x 2017-12-12 @geek add file location preference option +todotxtapp
(A) @geek completed task syntax highlighter rule needs tweak - it includes any character follows with whitespace - starting in the middle of the line +todotxtapp
(B) @geek design new app icon +todotxtapp
(C) @geek add priority shortcut cmd+up/down or similar +todotxtapp
asdasdasdasdasa x dsljhdsfkljg dhsklf sdaf
```

In practice, it only needs to match the first line. But it matches the half part of the second line and the last line.
See result here: http://take.ms/S2PEL

Comment: Strange, and I could find no documentation which discusses this behavior.  As your working Regex101 demo shows, I would expect your pattern to work as you might think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with CodeMirror, but going off of documentation,

> Simple modes (loosely based on the Common JavaScript Syntax Highlighting Specification, which never took off), are state machines, where each state has a number of rules that match tokens.

The regexp does not work on lines, it works on *tokens*. Thus, `asdasdasdasdasa`, `x`, `dsljhdsfklhg` are all tested individually; and, unsurprisingly, `x` matches `/^(x ).*$/`.

It seems you want something like this (you might need to tweak it, as I can't test it):

```
{regex: /x/, token: "task-completed", sol: true}
```

> `sol`: boolean
>
> When true, this token will only match at the start of the line. (The ^ regexp marker doesn't work as you'd expect in this context because of limitations in JavaScript's RegExp API.)

EDIT: I must say, I am not quite sure what's happening at `syntax`.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, before trying it, I read the source of the simple mode and it's simply checking sol in the rule definition. Your suggestion worked like a charm.